# SQLite : How to select all, and additionally set a value for some column

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-room

I have the following query.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM sounds GROUP BY artistId ORDER BY artist")
        List<Sound> getArtists();
```

I want to select all, and then set the `isDirectory` to return as true for all rows that are returned in this query?

I tried this :

```
@Query("SELECT *, " +
                "artist AS title," +
                "isDirectory AS 'true' " +
                "FROM sounds GROUP BY artistId ORDER BY artist").
```

I realize this is for column alias, is there a way to use something similar to `AS`, but not for name, but rather for value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `'true' AS isDirectory`  not the other way around

Comment: Ok, compiles well, but returns false for field `isDirectory `

Comment: It can't return false because there is no "false" value set anywhere, or is there any other field that could return false?

Comment: I hope you understand that the value `true` returned by the query is `TEXT` and not Boolean. So when you fetch it from db it is a `String` and as such should be compared.

Comment: yeah just figured that out, so this needs to be `@Query("SELECT *, artist AS title, :isDirectory AS isDirectory, soundId AS artistId FROM sounds GROUP BY artistId ORDER BY artist")
  List<Sound> getArtists(boolean isDirectory);`, then setting the var true from query method.